# How to get notified when user uninstall my application in android

Tags: android, uninstallation

I have checked this a lot and not found the solution that I should get a notification when someone tries to uninstall my application. I do not want to prevent users from uninstalling the app.

I have some services running in my backend for the users who are using the app, so I just want to stop those services for the user who uninstalled the app.

I saw some of the applications already doing this. can you please help me out to achieve this?

Comment: On-device there is no way you can check this as of now.

Answer (score 2):

You can send a push notification to your users. If the app is deleted, you'll get a 404 error for that registration token.

Comment: yes, that will be a good idea I think, but this would not be very quick, I mean I want to know as soon as the user uninstalled the application?